# Pygameでの画像透過処理

Tags: python3, windows-10, pygame

私は現在Pygameでソフトを制作しています。
画像透過処理について意見をお聞きしたいと思い質問させていただきます。
Pygameで作成したwindowで画像をフェードアウトさせたいと思っています。
なにか良い方法は無いでしょうか？
どうぞよろしくお願いします。
（Pillowなどの有名なライブラリであれば利用しても問題ありません）

Answer (score 1):

[set_alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30276322/8248751)でフェードアウトする方法がお手軽です。
ちなみにテキストなどのフェードアウトは[special_flagsにBLEND_RGBA_MULTを指定する](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52856474/8248751)ため、サンプルコードへついでに載せました。

```
import pygame as pg

# Todo パス名を変更すること
img_path = r"img\test.png"

def main(img_path):
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))

    # 画像初期化
    img_orig = pg.image.load(img_path).convert()
    colorkey = img_orig.get_at((0,0))               # 左上を透明色にする処理
    img_orig.set_colorkey(colorkey, pg.RLEACCEL)    # 左上を透明色にする処理
    img_surf = img_orig.copy()
    img_alpha = pg.Surface(img_surf.get_size(), pg.SRCALPHA)

    # テキスト初期化
    font = pg.font.SysFont(None, 64)
    blue = pg.Color('royalblue')
    txt_orig = font.render(u'Transparent.', True, blue)
    txt_surf = txt_orig.copy()
    txt_alpha = pg.Surface(txt_surf.get_size(), pg.SRCALPHA)

    alpha = 0
    isAdding = True

    while True:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                return

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))

        # 画像描画
        img_alpha.fill((255, 255, 255, alpha), special_flags=pg.BLEND_RGBA_MULT)
        img_surf = img_orig.copy()
        img_surf.set_alpha(alpha)         # 透過処理
        img_surf.blit(img_alpha, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(img_surf, (10, 50))

        # テキスト描画
        txt_alpha.fill((255, 255, 255, 255 - alpha))
        txt_surf = txt_orig.copy()
        txt_surf.blit(txt_alpha, (0, 0), special_flags=pg.BLEND_RGBA_MULT)
        screen.blit(txt_surf, (10, 10))

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)

        # 透明度更新
        if isAdding:
            alpha += 5
        else:
            alpha -= 5
        if alpha <= 0 or alpha >= 255:
            isAdding = not isAdding
            alpha = max(min(alpha, 255), 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main(img_path)
    pg.quit()
```