# pygameで、画像の透明度を変更する方法を教えてください。

Tags: 画像, pygame

pygame初心者です。

pygameで今、画像の透明度を変更する方法を今探しているのですが、検索しても出てこなくて...

まだ「def main:」などがよくわからないので
できればわかりやすく説明してくださりますと嬉しいです！
（少し日本語がおかしいかもしれませんがご了承ください）

Comment: こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に内容を明確化してみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765) 例えばこんな質問のように。[Transparent Image in Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50457855/9014308), [How do I blit a PNG with some transparency...?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1634208/9014308), [How can I make an Image with a transparent Backround in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62623341/9014308), [Pygameでの画像透過処理](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/54511/26370)

Comment: 次の投稿はあなたの質問の回答になりますか？ [Pygameでの画像透過処理](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/54511/pygame%e3%81%a7%e3%81%ae%e7%94%bb%e5%83%8f%e9%80%8f%e9%81%8e%e5%87%a6%e7%90%86)